# How to force copy/move dialog in Windows 8 to be always launched in the foreground?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

When I copy or move files in Windows 8, the copy/move dialog is sometimes launched in the foreground and sometimes in the background of other open file explorer windows.

I have found out that:

- The dialog is launched *in the foreground* when it was *in the foreground* at the end of last copy/move operation.
- The dialog is launched *in the background* when it was *in the background* at the end of last copy/move operation.

So for example, if I copy/move a file somewhere and watch the entire copy/move process, thus let the dialog in the foreground till the end, the dialog of a next copy/move operation is also launched in the foreground. Otherwise, when I copy/move a file somewhere and do not watch the process till the end, thus switch focus to another file explorer window, the dialog of a next copy/move operation is then launched in the background. I have tested this also in safe mode but the same thing happened.

I find it very annoying so I ask - Is there any option in Windows 8 to force copy/move dialog to be always launched in the foreground?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok, I asked this [Microsoft](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/) and they told me that this is "by design". The dialog is shown in background to avoid to interupt you and avoid accidental cancel click when the dialog comes to foreground and you type a text.

Comment: Thank you for your effort - but is it possible to change that behavior, for example by modifying registry or something else, or not?

Comment: I asked this too, but it looks like there is no way to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe 'DeskPins' utility helps us ? It can pin to foreground any window.
I begin a process of copying and pin the window. When i try to begin next copying new window was pinned to a foreground. This can be a save while MS is thinking.

Here's where i get it.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/DeskPins.shtml